# In React, what invokes returned function for things like higher order components and redux-thunk?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-context

My question is in regards to what invokes returned functions in React?  For example with redux-thunk, say I call the below function from componentDidMount() of an arbitrary component,

```
getCurrentPoll()
```

My redux-thunk action definition is below:

```
export const getCurrentPoll = pollId => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const currentPoll = await api.call('get', `polls/${pollId}`)
        dispatch(actionGetCurrentPoll(currentPoll))
        dispatch(removeError())
    } catch (err) {
        const { message } = err.response.data
        dispatch(addError(message))
    }
}
```

My understanding is that calling `getCurrentPoll()` will return the async dispatch function.  But what calls the async dispatch function that was returned?

Also for higher order components..say for the below function that injects the context api value into the component props.

```
const withRoomConsumer = Component => props =>
    <RoomContext.Consumer>
        {value => <Component {...props} context={value} />}
    </RoomContext.Consumer>
```

when you run `export default withRoomConsumer(RoomsContainer)`, what calls the returned function `props =>...`

Thank you in advance

Comment: For the `redux-thunk` example this is handled by the `redux-thunk` middleware - see https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware for a great explanation of the motivation and implementation of middleware with the implementation of the very simple thunk middleware at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redux-thunk creates a redux middleware and check if the action is a function, then call that function. You can check their [implementation here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js), it's very simple only 14 lines

React HOC returns a functional React component, and React will render that component as usual. (it can be a class component as well)